# What is the difference between packages qemu and qemu-native in Yocto?

Tags: qemu, yocto, bitbake

I would like to understand the relationship between the two packages because it seems that changing the source uri for 'qemu' causes build breakage for qemu-native.

I am not a Yocot/Bitbake expert, so a bit of clarification would go a long way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-native` just indicates it is a package built for the native platform (to be run in the native sysroot on the build host), and not for the cross-compiled target platform. `qemu` and `qemu-native` are both built from the same recipe: that's why changing SRC_URI affects both. The -native version is there because somewhere in the recipe it says

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

Comment: I can't quite understand why changing the SRC_URI to grab the sources from a private repo would cause one to build but not the other.  Are they dependent on each other ?

Comment: Well, you could always use `bitbake -e qem-native` to check for the value of SRC_URI. There might be some patch that's needed. Though, your best bet is to actually look at the build log, to find out what's failing during the build. Your question lacks all information needed to help you. (Error from build log, the complete SRC_URI etc). Your repo might also contain code that breaks one or the other, depending on your local changes.

Comment: What Anders said: if you want help with a specific build problem,  then you need to explain what the problem is.